# Trigger in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

why am I getting this error?

Question) write a trigger to restrict the insertion of commission more than salary.

**prog,**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMP2_TR
BEFORE INSERT ON EMP2
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.COMM > NEW.SAL)
BEGIN
    Raise_Application_Error (-20100, 'COMMISION MUST NOT BE GREATER THEN SALARY');      
END;
/
```

**error,**

```
SQL> INSERT INTO EMP2 VALUES(101,'RAMAN',100,1000);
INSERT INTO EMP2 VALUES(101,'RAMAN',100,1000)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20100: COMMISION MUST NOT BE GREATER THEN SALARY
ORA-06512: at "AYUSH.EMP2_TR", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'AYUSH.EMP2_TR'
```

**table,**

```
SQL> DESC EMP2    
 Name                                      Null?    Type    
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------------------    
 EMP_NO                                             NUMBER(3)    
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)    
 SAL                                                NUMBER(10,3)    
 COMM                                               NUMBER(10,2)
```

Comment: We don't know the emp2 columns...

Comment: SQL> DESC EMP2
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMP_NO                                             NUMBER(3)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)
 SAL                                                NUMBER(10,3)
 COMM                                               NUMBER(10,2)

Comment: You try to insert commission 1000 when salary 100 - so that behavior is just as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is:  Why are you doing this with a trigger?

You should be doing this with a constraint:

```
alter table emp2 add constraint chk_emp2_comm_sal check (comm <= sal);
```

Comment: Actually there is a question in my practical book asking to do this using trigger.

Comment: @AyushmanBokde . . . Your book should catch up with the times and show you how to do this correctly using constraints.

Comment: well that's true, but can it be done using trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: this seems to be a common practice in PL/SQL examples: using PL/SQL for stuff that should be done more efficiently in a different way. I never understood the reasoning behind examples like that. What's even worse are triggers to ensure referential integrity. I guess the teachers simply don't want to be bothered with coming up with real world examples.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I even get the didactic point . . . assuming it is phrased as "Let's implement this `check` constraint using a trigger".  That I can get.  But not "Solve this problem using a trigger."  That is close to saying "Solve this other problem using cursors (when they are not needed)".

Comment: well efficiency is important and not the question , therefor thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your insert does not specify the order of the values, so the order of the columns in the table is used. Most probably the `sal` column is defined before the `comm` column.

You need to list the columns in the insert statement:

```
insert into emp2 
  (empid, name, comm, sal) 
values 
  (101,'RAMAN',100,1000);
```

so that Oracle knows which value belongs to which column.

This is good coding practice anyway